# TeamCity doesn't recognize it's own MSSQL Database

Tags: database, teamcity, restore

I've a backup DB (MS SQL) of TeamCity 8.1.
I've the related TeamCity 8.1 data.
When I start TeamCity server and it connects to the DB, I get a message that Database is empty, and I've to create a new one, even though is the same DB that's been used by TeamCity.

I've no backups from TeamCity tools (maintainDB).

Even if I try to migrate or backup the data, I get an error message saying that the source database is empty.

I'd like to know if it's possible to get everything up and running with my current scenario. I tried TeamCity documentation but nothing worked.

I've one last option that is a month old TeamCity 8.1 backup. Can I restore it to a new TeamCity 9.1 installation, and just accept my loss?